# Ignore build step when a keyword in commit message is detected

Tags: deployment, teamcity, teamcity-9.1

I have a `VCS trigger` which starts build each time a new commit in specific branch is detected. But sometimes I want one of steps to be skipped. I decided to add a specific keyword to such commits.

I tried to use template and two configurations (one with step enabled and another with disabled) but there is no possibility to modify `VCS Trigger` properties in derived configurations. Also I can't add a second `VCS Trigger` neither to the configuration nor to the template: when I click "Add" there is no `VCS Trigger` in list.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have template then you can replace VCS trigger rules from hardcoded values with some parameter, e.g. %TRIGGER_RULES%. And in each build, that uses this template you could easily override this parameter for your needs. This should give you possibility to make something like

```
-:comment=.*do-not-trigger.*
```

But if you would like to skip only one step, then in this case you have to create some custom script for it and check commit message in it. The behaviour of build is simple: either build is executed and all steps are triggered, or build is not executed at all.